# Retrieving value of single tag of KML file

Tags: java, android, kml

I'm having difficulties trying to get the value of a KML tag, "href". There are about 200  records on the file and I can get almost all of them ok, but a few are cut.

KML example:

```
  <Style id="style104">
    <IconStyle>
      <Icon>
        <href>http://www.xxx/yyy/zzz/mmm.png</href>
      </Icon>
    </IconStyle>
  </Style>
    <Style id="style180">
    <IconStyle>
      <Icon>
        <href>http://www.xxx/yyy/zzz/sss.png</href>
      </Icon>
    </IconStyle>
  </Style>
  <Style id="style121">
    <IconStyle>
      <Icon>
        <href>http://www.xxx/yyy/qqq.png</href>
      </Icon>
    </IconStyle>
  </Style>
```

And here's the characters() on my code:

```
@Override
public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length)
        throws SAXException {
    elementValue = new String(ch, start, length).trim();

}
```

On debug, I can see how with the first and the last style, I get start and length correct values, but with the second style I get a shorter length:

```
**style104**:
start 0
length X
elementValue = http://www.xxx/yyy/zzz/mmm.png
OK

**style121**:
start 0
length Y
elementValue = http://www.xxx/yyy/zzz/mmm.png
OK

**style180**:
start 0
length 8
elementValue = http://w
NOK
```

So, my question here would be if anyone has found a similar problem with KML parsing with SAX, or if someone knows how the characters() gets the value of the tags? I'm out of ideas and any help would be much apreciated.

Thank you guys!

Comment: What has your characters() function to with  your problem? Don't you have a parse issue?

Comment: The characters() function is the one analyzing the tag content. On debug mode I've seen that the problem is that it's receiving wrong information on the length parameter. I don't think the problem is on the function, it has to be before that, but just in case...

Comment: Yes it is before that. So why not come to the point?